# Curious why no Curious received with positive record

Tags: support, badges

- [query 1](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202517/asking-record?UseIds=5994041)
- [query 2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/313876/do-you-have-a-positive-question-record-based-on-public-information?UserID=5994041)
- [deleted (and undeleted, because I found solution)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/601234/find-deleted-questions-by-user?UserID=5994041)

Both `0.9 >= 0.5`, [source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251172/323700)

If I count even the deleted&undeleted one, then it should be `~0.8 >= 0.5`, right? So... am I missing something, or what's going on?

Comment: Presumably you have other deleted posts that you've forgotten. You can't search for deleted questions per user in SEDE as AFAIK

Comment: You'll need to factor in your **eight** deleted questions too (one of which was closed before deletion, which counts double, all were deleted within 60 days).

Comment: I knew I forgot something. Well, stuff happens, heh. Would be nice to at least be able to search for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not meet the positive question record criteria yet.

You can't see them all, but you have 8 deleted questions (all deleted within 60 days of creating them). One of those was closed before it was deleted, so that counts double. None of these are voted down, but you do have one question with a negative score that wasn't deleted.

That means you have:

- 18 total questions
- 1 negative post
- 1 closed post
- 8 deleted posts

making a ratio of `(18 - 1 - 1 - 8) / 18 == 8 / 18 == 0.4444`.

You'll need another 2 new questions that are not closed, downvoted or deleted to hit the minimum 0.5 ratio. Other options are to undelete some of your deleted posts, or to improve the downvoted post to gain enough upvotes to no longer have a negative score. You only need to 'improve' one such post here.

I note that the progress indicator on your profile does tell you you don't yet meet the criteria; this appears to be working correctly.

Comment: Is there _any_ way how a user can see his/hers own deleted questions that are not [**recent**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/<id>)?

Comment: Quite sad though, a user should be able to read his/hers previous questions to get better. :/

Comment: Posts that old are usually no longer relevant to the asker, there is little point in exposing those *most of the time*.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr Just to note that when you get to 10k you *can* get your deleted questions by doing a search for: "user:me is:q deleted:1" but until then it's recent only.

Comment: @JonClements: TIL, a new feature [implemented over a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users/270562#270562). I removed my blanket statement that these can't be accessed at all without moderator help.

Comment: I wonder, will those deleted posts still remain in the statistics no matter _when_ I delete them? Or better said, if I delete my question after `60 days of creating them`, will it count as a negative factor to such badge too?

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr: questions that were deleted when they were at least 60 days old do *not* count as a negative factor for this badge. They are explicitly excluded.