# Can we change the completion bar on Curious badge to show the actual score from the formula?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges

As per the page on Curious Badge https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious

The Curious badge has two criteria to be awarded:

1. Ask a good question on 5 separate days
2. Maintain a positive question record

While the 1st part is very intuitive. The 2nd part generally gets ignored and causes confusion.

Can we change the bar to show the value from the formula instead?

> bar = (total questions - negative questions - closed - early deleted)/total
>   questions

[image]

These questions are a clear indicator that it's confusing to not show the actual score:

[Why didn't I get the Curious badge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294497/why-didnt-i-get-the-curious-badge)

[Why I haven't I received the "Curious" badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263351/why-i-havent-i-received-the-curious-badge)

[Curious why no Curious received with positive record](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346391/curious-why-no-curious-received-with-positive-record)

Past improvement on this hasn't helped new users much: [Misleading description of new Curious badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234956/misleading-description-of-new-curious-badge)

Comment: Similar issue for electorate. (if I recalled correctly it displays (current % vote on question) × 100/25)

Answer (score 7):

One major problem here is that users cannot calculate their question record on their own once any of their deleted questions is past 60 days old. They can't determine how the number was calculated, will assume it's *wrong*, and just end up here creating bug reports about the number we're showing being incorrect when it's not.

What you propose doesn't solve the problem. Showing a seemingly arbitrary number that they can't verify themselves doesn't help the confusion all that much.

Comment: Then show each individual number and let the user do the computation, or some way to go and check the actual progress on this Badge ?

Comment: Then stop counting deleted questions past 60 days, with something like `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/(total questions - long deleted)`. Disclosing the count of `long deleted` is a reasonable solution.

Answer (score -1):

> Can we change the bar to show the value from the formula instead?

What if someone has a positive question record without meeting the first criterion (ask a good question on 5 separate days).  You will have the same confusion because the user doesn't have the badge.  It doesn't matter how intuitive something is - if the bar shows 100%, a user will expect to get a badge.

Another issue is people are used to the bar always going up.  Sure there are situations for some badges that may cause it to slide back a little, but usually the changes are small and likely unnoticeable, but with that specific formula for "positive question record", you are likely to encounter larger variations in the score without doing anything just because of the dynamics of voting and closing and reopening and deletion of questions.

In short, this is not going to work, you'll just create different confusion and end up with the same "Why didn't I get my badge" questions, but you'll also now see "Why does the progress bar for the "Curious badge jump around so much".

This being said, the status quo is obviously confusing given the questions on meta, but it is hard to capture progress for a task with multiple criteria in a single bar.  Maybe the only solution is make 50% of the bar about the 5 questions, and the other 50% about the positive question record - but that doesn't really fix the confusion except now it won't show 100% until someone qualifies for the badge.  Or you just remove that badge from the "track next badge" feature.

Comment: You have made some good points. I feel it's better to see [0.35, 0.45, 0.32,...] then see 8/5 and an all green bar and still not get the badge. That "X" anyways looks like a close button instead of conveying that something is missing.

Comment: @VikashSingh but what about the first point - if the bar shows 100% and you still don't have the badge, isn't that just as confusing?  I can have 100% after asking 1 upvoted question, but I still won't get the badge,

Comment: True, But that can be handled within the formula by doing this `total questions = max(5, total questions)` and instead of `total_questions` we can call it something more intuitive.

Comment: You could also have two bars instead of trying to combine them into one.