# I'm curious about the tracking for the Curious badge

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, badge-progress

Since there is a hat on Winter Bash about the Curious badge (with the trigger for the hat being the same as for the Curious badge), I always check the tracking of the Curious badge, but I see that it seems that it tracks all your questions since you created an account, and writes: "need positive question record". I get it I do have downvoted questions, but wouldn't it be easier to see if it always resets the tracking to 0 when you have a downvoted question?

Here is the image of the tracking of my Curious badge:

[image: Curious badge tracking]

That actually doesn't help me at all. It would be pretty nice if it would reset to 0 every time you have an downvoted question, wouldn't it?

Comment: Relevant: [Why didn't I get the Curious badge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294497/11682469) (exact formula in answer)

Comment: @JeanneDark Seems to be that formula gives me true

Comment: @JeanneDark 0.7714285714285715

Comment: Did you include your deleted questions in your calculation?

Comment: @JeanneDark Where do I see my deleted questions?

Comment: Go to your profile, your questions and at the bottom is a link to your deleted questions. But you can only see deleted questions less than 60 days old. See also this related feature request: [Can we change the completion bar on Curious badge to show the actual score from the formula?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365172/11682469)

Comment: @JeanneDark Yeah I counted that

Comment: @JeanneDark 10k users can see all their own deleted posts by searching `deleted:1`. Can be combined with `is:q` for a question search

Comment: By the way I think they changed the hat's trigger. It really used to say "get the curious badge" or something like that, now it specifically says: *Each day during a 5-day period, ask a positively scored question and have no negatively scored, closed or deleted questions.*

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yeah it did.

Comment: I hope they did. I'm at .37 and don't have a chance of getting past .5 any time soon. Guess that's what I get for past me's mistakes :')

Comment: You have: 19 deleted questions, 6 closed questions and 22 questions with a negative score (a given question can be counted separately for each category) and you have asked 54 questions in total. So your score is (54 - 19 - 6 - 22) / 54 = 7 / 54 = 0.13.

Comment: @MartijinPieters Yeah I checked My ratio is around 0.255

Comment: @U11-Forward I gave you your exact score. Moderators can see all your questions including deleted ones.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, thanks Martijn.